# Finding the Javascript file and line number that causes some action using Firebug or some other tool

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug

Is it possible to use Firebug ( or some other tool ) to find out where some JS action came from ... ie which file and line.

For instance I have a button that causes a dropdown/slide and I want to find the Javascript that affected that drop down. I know I can probably find it by doing a lot of detective work; but if it was CSS I was looking for then all I would have to do is to look in Firebug and it would give me the file and line number. Is there any way of getting something similar for Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [firequery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) plugin for firefox you might be able to find some information about what events are attached to certain elements.

Other than this your best way to approach the problem would be using console logs to pinpoint which element is firing the event. Maybe by searching for class names or id's on that element would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome's Developer Tool, on the Elements tab, you'll see a column on the right with information about the selected element. One of the panels is called Event Listeners which shows the events bound to an element and the source location.